# Differentiating resistance equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

We were learning about strain gauges and somehow we did this:

From

$R = \frac{\rho L}{A}$

to

$dR = \frac{\partial R}{\partial \rho}d\rho + \frac{\partial R}{\partial L}dl + \frac{\partial R}{\partial A}dA  $

but I don't understand how this differential was formed?

Could anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

The next explanation is in "Physicist language". I bet Mathematicians to not read it to preserve their health (and by the way, to preserve my reputation).

Suppose you have a function of 3 variables : $f(x,y,z)$

If $x$ varies of a small value $dx$ while $y$ and $z$ are maintained constants, then $f$ varies of $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx$

This has the same signifiance as $df=\frac{df}{dx}dx$ where $\frac{df}{dx}$ is the usual derivative. But one write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ instead of $\frac{df}{dx}$ to remember that only the variable $x$ varies.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is called "partial derivative" because it is the usual derivative, but with regard to only one variable when several variables are present, the other variables being constant.

Similarly :

If $y$ varies of a small value $dy$ while $x$ and $z$ are maintained constants, then $f$ varies of $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy.$

If $z$ varies of a small value $dz$ while $x$ and $y$ are maintained constants, then $f$ varies of $dz=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz.$

Now, if $x$ , $y$ and $z$ varies together of respectively $dx$ , $dy$ , $dz$ , the total variation of $f$ is the sum of the three above variations :
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$$

In your "resistance formula" change the notations : Replace $R$ by $f$ , replace $\rho$ by $x$, replace $L$ by $y$ and replace $A$ by $z$ and you have the explanation.

I beg pardon to Mathematicians who did read it despite my warning and if they don't agree with Nonstandard Analysis.

Comment: How do you show that $ df = \frac{df}{dx} dx $? Is it because the dx cancels? And also, why is this nonstandard analysis? What would be the mathematical way

Comment: Did you never learn $df=f'dx$ with $f'=\frac{df}{dx}$ for a function $f(x)$? And forget my joke about non-standard analysis.

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative

Comment: oh right it's just that. cheers

Comment: I never met a $\color{red}{\texttt{physician}}$ that talks in that way. They usually talk about  fever, heart, etc$\ldots$

Comment: My God ! Physician instead of Physicist, what a slip of the pen! Why not Mathematician instead of Mathematicist ? Thanks to Felix Marin, the lapsus calami is corrected.